# Lista de meses en español en php

Tags: php, html, date, idioma

Hice una función que muestra en un `select` los meses y sus números, pero la lista solo se muestra en inglés y no hay manera de que salgan en español, alguna sugerencia?

```
    <select class="t_25p_25"><?php echo getAllMonths($dateMonth); ?></select>

    function getAllMonths($selected = ''){
    $options = '';
    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
    {
        $value = ($i < 10)?'0'.$i:$i;
        $selectedOpt = ($value == $selected)?'selected':'';
        $options .= '<option value="'.$value.'" '.$selectedOpt.' >'.date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i+1, 0, 0)).'</option>';
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Una forma manual de hacerlo, sería llenando un arreglo tú mismo con todos los meses y el index de ese arreglo se refiere al mes restandole 1, osea, `$meses = ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", ...]` y tomando en cuenta de que 1 como numero es "enero" pues lo pondrías `$meses[1-1]`, es una idea que se me ocurre.

Comment: Gracias, no fue asi exactamente como lo resolvi pero me diste la idea para poder resolverlo. (mas que nada por que aun debo entender bien como funcionan los arreglos)

Comment: Dale, con gusto. Puedes responder tu propia pregunta para que otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema lo puedan resolver. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

Ya he podido resolverlo, di un pequeño rodeo con un `switch` pero resulto, y la verdad, que pena no haber pensado en algo tan obvio XP

```
function getAllMonths($selected = ''){
   $options = '';
   for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
   {
       $value = ($i < 10)?'0'.$i:$i;
       $selectedOpt = ($value == $selected)?'selected':'';
       switch ($value) {
         case '01': $mes = 'Enero';break;
         case '02': $mes = 'Febrero';break;
         case '03': $mes = 'Marzo';break;
         case '04': $mes = 'Abril';break;
         case '05': $mes = 'Mayo';break;
         case '06': $mes = 'Junio';break;
         case '07': $mes = 'Julio';break;
         case '08': $mes = 'Agosto';break;
         case '09': $mes = 'Septiembre';break;
         case '10': $mes = 'Octubre';break;
         case '11': $mes = 'Noviembre';break;
         case '12': $mes = 'Diciembre';break;
         default: $mes = 'Non'; break;
       }
       $options .= '<option value="'.$value.'" '.$selectedOpt.' >'.$mes.'</option>';
   }
   return $options;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de apoyar lo que dice @DaxTter77 de añadir tu solución para compartirla, quiero poner la mía que se basa en establecer el lenguaje de localización para las fechas a español (ojo, que eso puede tener otras implicaciones que deberías revisar):

```
<?php setLocale(LC_TIME, "es_ES.UTF-8"); ?>
<html>
<body>
    <select class="t_25p_25"><?php echo getAllMonths(); ?></select>
    <?php 
        function getAllMonths($selected = '') {
            $options = '';
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                $value = ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i;
                $selectedOpt = ($value == $selected)?'selected':'';
                $options .= '<option value="'.$value.'" '.$selectedOpt.' >'.strftime("%B", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i+1, 0, 0)).'</option>';
            }
            return $options;
        }?>
</body>
</html>
```

He tenido que poner la llamada a `setLocale` al principio porque de otro modo no me lo reconocía bien. Además de esta llamada, he cambiado el método `date` que usas tú por el `strftime`, cambiando también el parámetro que se usa en esas llamadas

Comment: fue una de las cosas que intente, pero seguia saliendo en ingles, aunque puse Spanish en lugar de es_ES, tal vez fuera por eso